# Using select with reduce in jq?

Tags: select, jq, reduce

If I have a simple `reduce` expression:

```
reduce inputs as $line
([]; . + [$line])
```

*(this is roughly equivalent to `--slurp`: ignore that; it's just an example)*

...but I want to filter `inputs` somehow.

**Where do I put the `select`?**

Comment: There's one small mistake in your helpful blog post at blog.differentpla.net/blog/2019/01/11/jq-reduce. The erroneous sentence is the one beginning "The following example returns the last value passed to it:". You could fix it either by modifying the description to match the code, or vice versa, but in any case you might like to mention the def of `last` in builtin.jq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand your question completely, but I guess this should work

```
reduce (inputs | select(Your_filter)) as $line
([]; . + [$line])
```

Comment: It might be worthwhile emphasizing that this solution assumes that jq has been invoked with the -n command-line option.

Answer (score 0):

In the particular case given, a simpler solution is:

```
[inputs | select(...)]
```

In fact, it often happens that a solution using `reduce` can be simplified, e.g. as here or by using one of the built-in reduction filters (notably `add`).

Of course, when using `inputs` to avoid slurping, the -n command-line option is needed.